# python SSL connection

Tags: python-2.7, ssl

I am doing a project in python which I need to implement client creating a ssl connection to a server I also implement.

I used ssl.wrapsocket(), but for some reason when I sniff the traffic using Wireshark I only see the TCP handshake.

Here is my client side code:

```
import socket
import ssl
import os

SERVER_ADDRESS = ('**********', 10000)

#open a TCP socket
client_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_sock.settimeout(20000)

#connect to the server
client_sock.connect(SERVER_ADDRESS)

#start ssl handshake with the server
keyfile = os.path.dirname(__file__).replace('/', '\\') + '\\server.key'
certfile = os.path.dirname(__file__).replace('/', '\\') + '\\server.crt'

cli_ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(
    sock=client_sock,
    certfile=certfile,
    keyfile=keyfile,
    server_side=False,
    ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23,
    ca_certs=None,
    do_handshake_on_connect=False,
    suppress_ragged_eofs=True,

)
cli_ssl_sock.do_handshake()
```

Here is my server side code:

```
import socket
import ssl

SERVER_ADDRESS = ('**********', 10000)

keyfile = '/root/Desktop/server.key'
certfile = '/root/Desktop/server.crt'


#create TCP socket
server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#bind the socket
server_sock.bind(SERVER_ADDRESS)

#listen
server_sock.listen(5)

print 'server is listening ...'

#receiving connections
while True:
    conn_sock, client_address = server_sock.accept()
    print 'new connection from : ' + str(client_address)

    ssl_server_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(
                    sock=conn_sock,
                    certfile=certfile,
                    keyfile=keyfile,
                    server_side=True,
                    ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23,
                    ca_certs=None,
                    do_handshake_on_connect=True,
                    suppress_ragged_eofs=True,
                    )
```

Comment: Is the implementing all this stuff yourself important to your project? Or could you use existing libraries instead?

Comment: I have no problem using an exsiting libarary.

Comment: Are http(s) requests okay, or some other standard web request, or do you need something more custom? (I would generally suggest that you need a pretty good reason to do something that standard protocols can't. You're free to implement quite a bit server side in terms of you respond to a web request.)

Comment: The reason I ask is because there's a lot more existing tooling for HTTP. For server side stuff, you typically choose a web framework that speaks WSGI, and then it runs behind a web server. (E.g., you can use uWSGI or Gunicorn to run a Flask app behind Nginx.) Then you let the web server (e.g. Nginx) handle the TLS security. For client side, [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) is excellent. It usually "just works".